# number of lines no funciona en react-native

Tags: reactjs, input, text

tengo un problema con mi codigo, la verdad que no se si estoy haciendo algo mal, espero puedan ayudarme. Tengo que decir que soy bastante nuevo con React, tengan paciencia por favor.

estoy intentando crear un TextInput con un numero de lineas maximo, para ello, tengo este codigo pero no me funciona

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class UselessTextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: 'Write something' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
        multiline={true}
        numberOfLines={5}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

gracias.

Comment: ¡Hola Jhon! Es un  poco dificil saber que es lo que está fallando si no describes cuál es el error. Que significa "no me funciona"? Qué error obtienes? Que resultado obtienes?

Comment: hola @FranAcuna. no tengo ningun error simplemente no se restringen el numero de lineas. y necesito una forma de hacerlo. Ahora mismo, esta puesto para que haya un maximo de 5 lineas, sin embargo puedo escribir mas de 5 lineas. Necesito una forma de restringir esas lineas

Comment: Oh, ya veo. Y has probado utilizando ```maxHeight```? Estás probando en iOS o en Android?